# How to copy all files from dir and all sub-dirs with a particular set of extensions into another dir?

Tags: windows, powershell

Specifically, I want to write a powershell script to find every file with extensions.lib & .dll from directory X and all sub-directories of X recursively.  Then I want to copy them to directory Y.  All files should be put directly in Y, the directory structure of X is not to be copied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According that Y exists :

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath X -filter *.lib -Recurse | % {Copy-Item $_.fullname Y}
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath X -filter *.dll -Recurse | % {Copy-Item $_.fullname Y}
```

Comment: Good enough, although the multi-filter doesn't seem to work.  I just called it twice, once for *.lib and once for *.dll.

Comment: `-filter`supports only wildcars, while `-inlcude` supports regex. The one liner finally is:

`Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath X -include *.lib,*.dll -Recurse | % {Copy-Item $_.fullname Y}
`

Comment: @empo: When I do that, it copies every file, including the directories, although the directories are empty.

Comment: `ls X\*.* -include *.lib,*.dll -Recurse | % {Copy-Item $_.fullname Y}`

Comment: `copy-item -path X -include *.lib,*.dll -Recurse -destination Y`, sorry just guessing, I've windows at work only :P

Comment: Edited, sorry -filter doesn't take an array as parameter.

Comment: thanks Very much for the answer.
Is there any Other possible way to Include all the files from the source file to Destination file. for e.g to copy all *.dll, *.txt, *.exe etc... I have tried using (*.*). Its working fine but it also make a blank copy of all the folders inside of the Source folder in the destination which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: using PowerShell 4.0 you've got the `-File` switch in `Get-ChilItem`.

Comment: **Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath X -filter *.* -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false } | Foreach-Object   {Copy-Item $_.fullname  Y}**

This did the trick. Now able to copy all the files within the source folder without copying any other blank folders in the Destination. Thanks